# checking the string data in contains function by using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Checking data with targeting some sentence in when condition using **xslt -1.0**

example sentence : **END OF SERVICE FOR THIS DAY  ----($branchPay)**

using when condition if i check `contains($branchPay,'END OF SERVICE')` i will hard code as **END**

if suppose sentence somes with out spaces  : **END OFSERVICE FOR THIS DAY  --- ($branchPay)**

then  hard code as **END** is not working , at such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove spaces from `$branchPay` and check if it contains `ENDOFSERVICE`, i.e.:

```
contains(translate($branchPay, ' ', ''), 'ENDOFSERVICE')
```